# Secure Order form in wordpress?

Tags: security, wordpress, e-commerce, calculator

I realise this is very vague I'm just trying to work out if I can do something. How would I go about building something similar to this in wordpress? is it possible?

http://www.thesisonline.co.uk/

What it needs to do
1. User uploads a file
2. User fills in a form that calculates a cost
3. Cost is passed securely, to a secure form that the user can enter their credit card details and pay.

I imagine for the last step I'll have to use something to make it secure and all legal, sage pay etc. not sure which is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not an expert of WordPress but what you have mentioned is quite possible in WordPress with some coding skills and using any of existing e-commerce plugin available in WordPress.

How the cost will be calculated is entirely dependents upon you and how to set your business rules, once you have your business rules to calculate the cost you can proceed for payment.

This is the main secure and sensitive part of any e-commerce application and you have to integrate your application with Payment Gateways so that things can be handled by the gateway itself for you (like security and other things)

i just saw this plugin of WordPress [WordPress E commerce plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) and it provides integration with payment gateway which means your most of the work has already been done by the plugin itself

but if you are working towards a serious e-commerce application always suggest you to choose any e-commerce platform rather than an extension of a platform which is developed with some other objectives.